# Why did this trap in the dead circle?

Tags: java

When I try to use *FileReader*、*FileWriter* to copy a plain text file, it trapped in a dead circle.That's confused me a lot. I'd appreciate it if someone can help me.

```
FileReader in = new FileReader("./src/io/copyFile/CopyFileTest01.java");
FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Copy1.java");

char[] chars = new char[1024 * 512]; // once max copy 1MB
```

When I try to copy file like the followed way，it's ok.

```
while (true) { // ok
    int count = in.read(chars);
    System.out.println("count = " + count);
    if (count == -1) {
        break;
    }
    out.write(chars, 0, count);
}
```

However, when I try use the other way, it will trap in the dead circle.

```
int readCount = 0;
while ((readCount = in.read(chars)) != -1) { // dead circle
    System.out.println("readCount = " + readCount);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars)); // bad
    out.write(chars, 0, readCount); writing after reading
}
```

I can't find the reason, and it puzzleed me a lot. I'd appreciate it if someone can help me.

There is the complete code.

```
package io.copyFile;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CopyFileTest02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReader in = null;
        FileWriter out = null;
        
        try {
            in = new FileReader("./src/io/copyFile/CopyFileTest01.java");
            out = new FileWriter("Copy1.java");
        
            char[] chars = new char[1024 * 512]; 
            int readCount = 0;
            while ((readCount = in.read(chars)) != -1) { // dead
                System.out.println("readCount = " + readCount);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars)); // bad
                out.write(chars, 0, readCount); 
            }
            
            // flush
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok. I found that when remove the followd bolck, this code can work well.However, when I added the followed block, it will never exit the loop.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars));
```

When I added that `Arrays.toString(chars)`, It will print ',' in console and never stop like the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFyUO.png)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "trapped in a dead circle" - that's not standard terminology. Do you mean it ended up in a loop, and never exited the loop? What did the read count show in the broken version?

Comment: Sorry. Yeah, I mean "It ended up in a loop, and never exited the loop"

Comment: Okay, so what does the output look like? Can you provide a [mcve] we can copy, paste, compile and run that will demonstrate this? (You've got most of the bits there, but I want to make sure we don't miss something that turns out to be important...)

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I use Stack Overflow. I don't know how to provide a minimal reproducible example. Could I paste the code in the comment?

Comment: No, edit your question and paste the code in there. (But what you pasted is *not* a complete example. What I'm looking for is a complete program, including imports, that lets me copy, paste, compile and run, in order to reproduce your problem.)

Comment: Sorry, my apologies. I have paste the  minimal reproducible example. I had miss a block before.

Comment: Hint: this really isn't minimal. You've got a commented out chunk of code, a file comment that's unnecessary, and just calling `in.close()` and `out.close()` explicitly is fine for the sake of reproducing the problem. (You can declare that your method throws IOException.) You haven't imported `Arrays` though... Here's a 24 line version... less than half the length of yours. https://gist.github.com/jskeet/97be68b61ae13138b9df744f743ed468

Comment: More importantly though, the program still doesn't fail for me. Is the `Arrays` class actually one within the `io.copyFile` package, so it's a custom class that you haven't shown us? Perhaps *that's* where the bug is? Have you tried debugging through your code?

Comment: Thanks. `Arrays` is the `java.util.Arrays`. It cannot work, when I try to print the `chars` array in the loop.

Comment: What indication do you get that the loop never ends?  Did you put a print statement outside the loop at the end to see if it ever prints.  Also, some IDE's limit console output if not set correctly.   Are using an IDE and if so, which one?

Comment: @posper did you see my last comment?

Comment: If your issue is that garbage is being printed, that’s probably because `Arrays.toString(chars)` is printing the entire buffer and ignores `readCount`.  But that wouldn’t cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @WJS Thank you. I have tried to put a print statement outside the loop. When I remove the `Arrays.toString(chars)`, everything is OK. However, when I add that, it print the ',' in the console and never exit the loop. What I used is `eclipse` IDE.

Comment: @VGR Thank you very much. But when I added that `Arrays.toString(chars)`, It will print ',' in console and never stop like the picture.

Comment: You are printing 524,288 char values.  Of course it takes a long time.  Are you sure you need to print every single char value that gets copied?

Comment: Check your console settings.  It is possible that some characters are causing the output to stop.  Or perhaps some insufficient buffer handling.   Check the Scroll lock, Interpret Ascii control characters, buffer size, etc.